# Is there any certification toolkit for WP8 apps?

Tags: windows-phone-8, app-certification-kit

I am developing a new application that will target the new WP8 platform.

Previous versions of Phone SDK, like  WP7.1 or WP7.5 SDK contained special toolkit to test you XAP before submission for some obvious problems (like some mandatory image files missing).

A similar function is fulfilled by the WACK for Win8 Desktop Apps.

But I can't find any toolkit for testing my WP8 applications. The only option I found is to "Windows Phone Application Analysis" provides me with some performance information but there seem to be no static rule-based check of the XAP package performed.

Am I missing some software installation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For WP8 apps, right click on your project in VS2012 Solution Explorer ---> Click "Open Store Test Kit". You can read more about what's being tested for on MSDN @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394032(v=vs.105).aspx

[image: Open Store Test Kit]