# Is there an app certification kit for Windows Phone 8?

Tags: visual-c++, windows-phone-8, app-certification-kit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any certification toolkit for WP8 apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962397/is-there-any-certification-toolkit-for-wp8-apps)

I am trying to use a 3rd party C++ library in my Windows Phone 8 app and I wish to find out whether this library's binaries use any API not supported by the Windows Phone 8 OS.  For Windows 8 store apps, I can use [Windows App Certification Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27414) to figure this out.  Is there such a thing for Windows Phone 8 app as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See answer to the same question @ [Is there any certification toolkit for WP8 apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962397/is-there-any-certification-toolkit-for-wp8-apps/13962554#13962554)

I'm not specifically sure if that store test kit checks for static verification of C++ binaries. But WP8 Store Ingestion definitely does.