# How to run Windows Phone Store Cetrification Kit from command line?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-store

I want to use Jenkins to automate build process and I need to run Store Certification Kit to examine my windows phone 8 .xap file. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate? See the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962397/is-there-any-certification-toolkit-for-wp8-apps

Comment: Sorry but no( This is about testing from UI, I want to know how to test windows phone 8 app from command line

Answer (score 1):

Sudenly I found that Windows Phone 8 Store Certification Kit is part of Visual Studiuo 2012, it is not single app. It means that Certification Kit cant be used from command line