# App submition issues

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to publish an app for the Windows Phone 8 market, and the instructions say to create an app package.
But I cannot do this.
They say to go to `Project` then `Store` but I cannot find the store option.
What can I do???
I have built the solution with the options `Release` and for `Any CPU`.

Also the app certification kit for Windows Phone 8 keeps giving the message:

> "This version of windows app certification kit does not support this type of package".

I do not know if this is because of the issue about not find the `Store` option (explained above).

Comment: The answer to your first question is pretty simple, whenever you build Visual Studio creates a XAP, there's nothing special you need to upload just that, should be in:
`<project_dir>/Bin/ARM/Release/<project_name>_Release_ARM.xap`


Assuming of course that you build for ARM on Release mode, still searching for an answer to part 2 though.

Comment: Nevermind, part 2 solved - WACK for Windows Phone only seems to support WP8.1, as per: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962397/is-there-any-certification-toolkit-for-wp8-apps

Answer (score 0):

As per my original comments, since I have an answer to both parts now, the file that needs uploaded to the store should just be the same XAP that you're attempting to use for WACK, located at:

```
<project_dir>/Bin/ARM/Release/<project_name>_Release_ARM.xap
```

When you build for ARM and Release (which as I understand is the best version for upload)

The reason you can't use WACK, as far as all my research goes is because it supports Windows Phone 8.1 (and above, when there is an above)
See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/apps/bg127575

> With this release, the Windows App Certification Kit now supports the following app types:
>
> - Desktop apps for Windows 7, Windows 8, and Windows 8.1
> - Windows Store apps for Windows 8 and Windows 8.1
> - **Windows 8.1 Phone apps**

See: [Is there any certification toolkit for WP8 apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962397/is-there-any-certification-toolkit-for-wp8-apps) for the appropriate way to manually check WP8 apps prior to submission.